# Why do I receive NameError when using input() on Jupyter Notebook (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Why do I receive NameError when inputting the name 'Timby' in the below sequence of images:

[image]

***After entering input:***

[image]

Comment: when calling a variable in the print you need to use the syntax like this print(f"Welcome {name}!")  What you typed would work for an assignment.

Comment: It is in fact 'Python 3' notebook!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Jupyter Notebook Python3 kernal path was pointing to Python2 version as outlined in this post: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270

The soultion was to install with input `ipython3 kernel install` in terminal.